# How can I say "Yes, I am" and "No, I am not" in French?

Tags: expressions, questions

Well, a very simple question,but I just dunno its answer.

Like, when someone ask "Are you French?" "Are you hungry?" "Are you Danny Smith?" , how can I answer those questions, not only with "oui" or "non", but also with something like "I am" or "I am not" in English ? THX a lot!

Well, what really confuses me is that, should I answer with " Je suis" or " J'en suis"

Comment: Are you Charlie Gordon? Oui, c'est moi.

Answer (score 5):

It does not sound natural in French but you should use "***Oui, je le suis***" where "*le*" would stand for French, or hungry. "***Oui, c'est moi***" would work well if you're Danny Smith.

If you want something generic, it would sound more natural to say "***Oui, c'est le cas***" (Yes, it is the case) which works for everything.

Comment: Wowowowo Thx   explained everything! so,,, you don't really say "i am "or"i am not "in french?

Comment: Definitively, no, we don't. De manière définitive, non. De manière définitive, non, on ne le dit pas. :)

Comment: @user98163 Hi, please note in all the examples you provided, the auxiliary _to be_ is used; this is not the case in French, where in one case you have something like "do you have hunger" and therefore you won't find a one size fits all verb and pronoun approach to express all of those, except as stated in the answers. Thanks!

Comment: Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 4):

You can just say "oui" or "non". This isn't like in English: a one-word answer is perfectly acceptable.

Or if you want a longer answer, you can just repeat the sentences. "Es-tu Français ? Oui, je suis Français.", "Est-ce que tu as faim ? Non, je n'ai pas faim."

Comment: Hahaha thanks a lot ! I've been wondering about it for a long time  